# Creating a vector with other vector`s index as elements in VHDL

Tags: vector, indexing, vhdl

I have a std_logic_vector like this one as input: v1 = "10001010" and I want to create another vector like this one: v2 = X"00000731", where X"7", X"3", and X"1" represent the index of the first vector (v1) where the value is '1'.

v1(1) = '1', v1(2) = '0', v1(3) = '1', etc.

Please help me with some coding examples that can create v2.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
variable base : natural := 0;
....
v2 <= (others => '0');
for i in v1'right to v1'left loop
  if v1(i) = '1' then
    v2(base+3 downto base) = to_unsigned(i,4);
    base := base + 4;
  end if;
end for;
```

Answer (score 0):

v2 can be generated with this function, with v1 as std_logic_vector(8 - 1 downto 0):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
function v1_to_v2(v1 : std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
  variable v2_v   : std_logic_vector(4 * v1'length - 1 downto 0);
  variable ones_v : natural;
begin
  ones_v := 0;
  v2_v := (others => '0');
  for idx in 0 to v1'left loop
    if v1(idx) = '1' then
      v2_v(4 * ones_v + 3 downto 4 * ones_v) := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(idx, 4));
      ones_v := ones_v + 1;
    end if;
  end loop;
  return v2_v;
end function;
```

The function can close timing at ~220 MHz in an Altera Cyclone IV E
(EP4CE6E22A7) FPGA, when there are flip-flops on v1 and v2.

Whether this is an acceptable solution depends on the detailed problem that you
are trying to solve.

Also, not that the format you have chosen for v2 will result in v2 =
X"00000000" when v1 = "00000000" as for "00000001".  That may be OK, depending
on the problem details.

Answer (score 0):

We've had a similar problem in the past. The best solution we found was to use a shift register for v2: you loop through v1's elements, and you shift in the loop index whenever you find a '1' in v1.

Here's a function that does what you need:

```
  type output_type is array (7 downto 0) of unsigned(2 downto 0);

  function find_ones(v1: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)) return output_type is
    variable v2: output_type := (others => "000");
  begin
    for i in v1'range loop
      if v1(i) = '1' then
        v2 := v2(6 downto 0) & to_unsigned(i, 3);
      end if;
    end loop;
    return v2;
  end;  

  -- results:
  --   find_ones("00000000") --> "000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000"
  --   find_ones("11111111") --> "111_110_101_100_011_010_001_000"
  --   find_ones("10001010") --> "000_000_000_000_000_111_011_001"
```

Because this solution is based on a shift-register, it is easy to implement in a clocked fashion and process one element at a time if you want it, or even pipeline the whole process.